# Disabled a button based on credit date expiry date validation in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have fields of credit card expiry date.Below code user enter a month and year

```
<input class="expiry-month exp" name="card_exp_month" id="card_exp_month" required>
<input class="expiry-year exp" name="card_exp_year" id="card_exp_year" required>
```

I am getting current month and year from php date() function.

```
<?php
$month= date('n');
$year= date('y');
?> 
<input type="text" name="curr_month" id="curr_month" value="<?php echo $month;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="curr_year" id="curr_year" value="<?php echo $year;?>"/>
```

This button will be disabled when user enter a expiry month or year less to current month or year

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd' name='next' value='Next' id="billing_nxtBtn" />
```

and jquery code

```
$( ".exp" ).keyup(function() {
var exp_month = $("#card_exp_month").val();
var exp_year = $("#card_exp_year").val();

var curr_month = $("#curr_month").val();
var curr_year = $("#curr_year").val();


if(exp_month < curr_month  || exp_year < curr_year){
    $("#billing_nxtBtn").attr("disabled",true);
}else if(exp_month > curr_month  || exp_year > curr_year) {
    $("#billing_nxtBtn").attr("disabled",false);
} 
});
```

I want that when user enter a expire month or year less then to current month or year then button will be disabled and when user enter a expire month or year greater then to current month or year then button will be enabled.

Issue is that button is not disbaled when user enter a expire month or year less then to current month or year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues. One is because you're not removing the `disabled` attribute; you need to use `removeAttr()`. Your logic is also flawed, as if I selected `01/2019` then the button would be disabled as the month is less than the current month - you're not taking in to account years.

There is also a couple of logical improvements you can make, such as using `input` instead of `keyup` (in case people copy+paste values, or use other entry methods for accessibility) and use `prop()` instead of `attr()`. That way you can simply provide the boolean condition as the argument.

Also just FYI, this is not secure in the slightest; it's ridiculously easy to break. You should provide this client side validation as a courtesy to users only and do the business critical date check on the server side.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(".exp").on('input', function() {
  var exp_month = $("#card_exp_month").val();
  var exp_year = $("#card_exp_year").val();

  var curr_month = $("#curr_month").val() || 0;
  var curr_year = $("#curr_year").val() || 0;

  $("#billing_nxtBtn").prop('disabled', exp_year < curr_year || (exp_year == curr_year && exp_month < curr_month));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="expiry-month exp" name="card_exp_month" id="card_exp_month" required>
<input class="expiry-year exp" name="card_exp_year" id="card_exp_year" required><br />

<input type="text" name="curr_month" id="curr_month" value="6" />
<input type="text" name="curr_year" id="curr_year" value="18" />

<input type='button' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd' name='next' value='Next' id="billing_nxtBtn" disabled/>
```

Comment: Thank u for helping but In chrome browser is not working button is enabled

Comment: That's odd as the snippet above is working fine for me in Chrome. Can you check the console for errors

Comment: Is there way by default button is disabled when expire month or year is greater then current month then button is enaled otherwise its still disabled?

Comment: I don't really understand what that means, however this logic is fairly standard date validation. It simply disables the button if the month/year entered is before the current date.

Comment: on my side button is not disabled

Comment: Check what's being output by PHP in to the hidden fields

Comment: <input type="text" name="curr_month" id="curr_month" value="6" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: <input type="text" name="curr_year" id="curr_year" value="18">

Comment: That's identical to what's in the working example above. Sorry, without a way of recreating the problem I can't offer any solutions

Comment: Same here, by default the button is enabled on Chrome. Certainly because there's no default values for fields, so, comparison `undefined < 18 == false` gives `$("#billing_nxtBtn").prop('disabled', false); //enabled`

Comment: Good point. I added defaults for the values and set the button to disabled by default.

Comment: @Arslan explain what?

Answer (score 0):

You should place your jquery constant value with PHP constant date, not get it from input field (which is dynamic value by user input), example code as below:

```
$( ".exp" ).keyup(function() {
    var exp_month = $("#card_exp_month").val();
    var exp_year = $("#card_exp_year").val();

    var curr_month = parseInt('<?= date("n");?>');
    var curr_year = parseInt('<?= date("Y");?>');


    if (exp_year < curr_year) {
        $("#billing_nxtBtn").attr("disabled", true);
    } else if (exp_year > curr_year) {
        $("#billing_nxtBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        if (exp_month >= curr_month) {
            $("#billing_nxtBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#billing_nxtBtn").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u try to use Jquery.change Method

```
$("#card_exp_month,#card_exp_year").change(function(){
 var exp_month = $("#card_exp_month").val();
 var exp_year = $("#card_exp_year").val();

 var curr_month = $("#curr_month").val();
 var curr_year = $("#curr_year").val();


 if(exp_month < curr_month  || exp_year < curr_year){
    $("#billing_nxtBtn").attr("disabled",true);
 }else if(exp_month > curr_month  || exp_year > curr_year) {
   $("#billing_nxtBtn").attr("disabled",false);
 } 
});
```